# Mouse Events on WPF Page - On sub controls only?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I am working on a C# WPF Project. The MainWindows holds only a `Frame Control` that is used to navigate to different Pages.

On one Page I use a `Button` to show a `PopUp`. Now I would like to hide this Popup when the Mouse leaves it and moves above the `Page`.

```
<Page x:Class="Name.SpaceMainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  Title="MainPage"
  MouseMove="Page_MouseMove">

    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Some Label"/>
        <Label Content="Other Label"/>
        <Button Name="PopupButton" Content="Popup" Click="MenuButtonClick" /> 
        <Label Content="Third Label"/>

        <Popup Name="ExtrasPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopupButton}" Placement="Top" PopupAnimation="Scroll">
            <StackPanel Background="LightGray">
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Page>


public partial class MainPage : Page {
    ...

    private void MenuButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ExtrasPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Page_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Move: " + e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this));
    }
}
```

**The Problem:** The Page_MouseMove is only executed when the mouse moves above of of the child controls (the labels or the button). If the mouse moves above the empty space of the page, the event does not fire.

The same is true for any other mouse event such as MouseDown, MouseEnter, MouseLeave, etc... This is quite strange behaviour. Is this intended or am I making any mistake?

Comment: Try `<Page Background="Transparent"`. Mouse events only fire on Background not null.

Comment: @LPL Thank you very much! This was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better idea to register to the `MouseLeave` event on the Button or whatever control you want to use.

```
<Button Name="PopupButton" Content="Popup" Click="MenuButtonClick" MouseLeave="Menu_MouseLeave" />
```

And in the code behind simply hide the popup when mouse leaves the button:

```
private void Menu_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   ExtrasPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: The Popup is shown on Button Click and it contains some controls (CheckBox, Buttons, etc.) as well. Thus the mouse has to leave the button to reach the controls inside the popup...